# Get The value of text Field while form submit in php

Tags: php, forms

how to get the value of input box while submitting the form in php

i need the url like this
`www.example.com/te/?a=test&firstname=blabla`

```
<form action="te/?a=test" method="post">

<input type="text" name="firstname" />


<input type="submit" name="button" />

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a clearer description of what values you want to grab at which point exactly. Do you need the values *before* or *after* the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="te/" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="a" value="test" />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form method to be "get" instead.

That'll give you the results you're expecting.